# Make And Configure Form Variations

Tags: make, configure

I see some installation instructions that take the form of:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

And others that take the form of:

```
./configure && make install
```

Are there any differences in how these different forms function?

Relatedly, I've seen variations of configure, such as:

```
./configure
./Configure
./config
```

Why do different packages require the configure command to be written in a particular way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form:

```
./configure && make install
```

Will only run `make install` if the configure stage is successful. The `make install` also typically depends on the software being built and `make` handles this.

Other case variants are normally hand crafted configuration scripts rather ones build using `autoconf`.

Answer (score 1):

Well `make` command will compile the source code and will generate binaries using `Makefile`.

While `make install` will map these binaries to `install` target and will just copy the binaries to their destinations.

However using only `make install` will work as it depends upon the `make` step but there is a good reason to use them separately and i.e. **privilage**.
You can compile the source code using normal user who just requires permissions to access the compiler but the `make install` step copies the binaries to destinations such as `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` which requires permissions of the root. So both are used separately as

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Well the reason behind different names of `configure` is well suggested by @danblack that `these are normally hand crafted configuration scripts rather ones build using Autoconf`. Because the configuration scripts that Autoconf produces are by convention called [`configure`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Making-configure-Scripts.html#Making-configure-Scripts).